# Replicating MySQL array formatting in Javasript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have 5 mysql tables that i need a variety of data from in several different scripts that all reference each other using an id's located in 1 or more column.

I need to create a master query that replicates the array structure exactly as it was imported from mysql AND ALSO needs error handling for each field before it writes to an array to determine if it needs to write the value to an array, or write it as null.

So far the script is looking like this:

```
    const items = [];
    // Items
    for (let i = 0; i < gameItems.length; i++) {
        if (gameItems[i].id) { 
            items.push({ id: gameItems[i].id }); 
        } else { 
            items.push({ id: null }); 
        }
        if (gameItems[i].identifier) { 
            items.push({ identifier: if (gameItemParams[i].custom_name)       
            { 
                items.push({ custom_name: gameItemParams[i].custom_name });   
            } 
        else { 
            items.push({ custom_name: null }); }
        }
    }
```

The problem, or my lack of ability to figure out the logic on how to execute the code correctly, is that in order to attach multiple fields of data to the same row in an array the values must be comma separated.

Individual pushes like above add data to the next row instead of the same object which renders the array.length properly useless because there is a new row for every single field so instead of having 1 row with 10 pieces of data attached, i would have 10 rows each with 1 piece of data.

Is there a way to perform error handling for each field i need to call from the tables or is there another way to add data to the same object after a row has already been pushed.

This is how the newly created array must be structured:
https://puu.sh/E7ogn/61c3117d3b.png

This is how the array is currently being structured with individual pushes:
https://puu.sh/E7oh7/422541a70d.png

Maybe if it is possible to break in the middle of an `array.push` i can then add error handling in the `push block` but was unable to find if it can be done.

Comment: Can you please provide sample output?

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < gameItems.length; i++) {
console.log(`the id is ${items[i].id} and called ${items[i].identifier}`)
}

at the moment to pull the data i need that should be in the same row:

``items[0].id and items[1].identifier`` so it cant be looped or utilized with .length.

There is no immediate output because the function is used in several different contexts. This will enable my code to be much more flexible if i can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are pushing an object every time. Instead of that, you need to create an object with all of fields and then push it to the array.

Other problem of your code is that you can use an `if` statement into a assigment statement. You need to use a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to do that or extract this conditional from the assigment.

```
const items = [];
// Items

for (let i = 0; i < gameItems.length; i++) {
    var object = {};

    if (gameItems[i].id) {
        object.id = gameItems[i].id;
    } 
    else {
        object.id = null; 
    }

    if (gameItems[i].identifier) { 
        object.identifier = (gameItemParams[i].custom_name) ? items.push({ custom_name: gameItemParams[i].custom_name }); : items.push({ custom_name: null }); 
    }

    items.push(object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the data mentioned in https://puu.sh/E7oh7/422541a70d.png.
You have data like

```
gameItems=[{id:0}, {identifier:"master-ball"}, {category_id:34}, {"custom_name":"Master Ball"}];
```

I suggest that instead of making items as an array, Please create temporary object item and then push it to items.

```
let items = [];
let item = {
    id:null,
    identifier: null,
    custom_name: null
};
for (let i = 0; i < gameItems.length; i++) {
    if (gameItems[i].id !== undefined) {
        item.id = gameItems[i].id;
    }

    if (gameItems[i].identifier !== undefined) {
        item.identifier = gameItems[i].identifier;
    }

    if (gameItems[i].custom_name !== undefined) {
        item.custom_name = gameItems[i].custom_name;
    }
}

items.push(item);
```